# Reading radiology reports: What do two numbers separated by a slash mean?

Tags: terminology, mri, medical-imaging

The following is an excerpt from the "findings" section of an MRI radiology report. What do the instances of two numbers separated by a slash mean?

> There is a lesion within the spinal canal at T2-3 posteriorly (**14/8**). There is a large one at T11-12 protruding into the right neural foramen (**17/27**).

These seem to denote some kind of location or frame of the MRI scan but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I called the radiology office and the technician I talked with said that the numbers should denote the **series** and **frame** in which the (in this case) lesions can be found. He said that these numbers would normally be accompanied with markup such as "series 14, image 8" or the like and that this abbreviated form is non-standard.

So for "14/8" I needed to go to the 8th image in the 14th series in the study. Note however that one of the software programs I used to view the MRI used a 0-indexed system to number the images meaning that the first image is viewed as image 0 and the 8th image as image 7.

Comment: Good idea to simply call the technician and ask him what the heck he has written. I like your pragmatism. 

Although I doubt that anyone is going to benefit from the answer due to it uniqueness (and I'd wish to be proven wrong), you get a +1 from me. 
It is quite annoying on Health.SE when people ask us questions that they should ask their doctor. Thanks for also asking your doctor!